# How to stop "tail -f" within a running script?

Tags: logs, kill, tail

How can you stop a `tail -f` command after seeing a specific string/word?

I'm trying to follow an expanding log and stop the `tail` after finding
a specific word. Is there any `kill` command for that? I'm just starting with UNIX.

Comment: Surely, `tail -f` is a command that you ran from the command line? So then doing a Ctrl C

Comment: actually no, ill be using it inside a script. I wanted to follow a log that is expanding then i want to stop the tail command if it see a specific string.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable the grep line buffering if you want to tail file with ongoing writing:

```
tail -f your_file | grep --line-buffered your_pattern
```

else if the file is static you can grep your file the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: tail -f log.txt | grep --line-buffered "error"
like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep -f 'tail -f your_filename'|xargs kill
```